Can a portable jump starter drain my car battery if being used for something else?
I’ve recently went to my dealership to take a look at my battery that I purchased not that long ago and was still under warranty. Well person says that what’s draining my battery is my dash camera, okay disconnect from car entirely and start using my jump starter that also acts like a battery to power it. Get the same problem again and take it back to dealership they replace the battery and tell me now it’s my jump starter powering my dash camera that draining my battery? But it’s not connected to my car at all! How does that make sense?

Wow, this dealership has free coffee in the waiting room and they serve baloney sandwiches too!

What makes sense to me is, it's time for a new mechanic/shop. Obviously they don't know what they are talking about. If the jump start battery is powering the camera and is connected to nothing else, there's no way it's draining the vehicles battery. I'm with @MTA, as what was said in the comment is spot on.
